# Button below UICollectionView not positioning correctly with constraints depending on size of content within (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, constraints

So I have a collection view within a UIView that is contained in a scroll view. (See below)
[image]

The collection view's content within changes size depending on the tab selected.. When the number of items in the collection view is small (I.E. <= 4 items), I want to show the next button at the **bottom** of the screen. If the collection view's content is larger (I.E. >4 items), I want to allow the screen to be scrolled down (which works currently), and the next button to be placed **below** the collection view's content.

On first loading of the screen, on the tab with <=4 items, the next button is placed in the correct position. If I switch to the tab with >4 players, the next button is placed correctly below the collection view as expected. However, when I switch back to the tab with <=4 players, the next button is placed in the incorrect position, much higher up on the screen.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Now back to the tab with less players, issue arises:**

[image]

See issue here:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/12eREBZlBZoCs-F5DJd-I26YcLc3pRqRJ/view?usp=sharing

Notice how when I switch back from forwards to midfielders, the next button is placed incorrectly where as the first time on midfielders the next button was placed correctly.

My code for resizing the collection view & changing the position of the next button is below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        //Setup Img & Label
        cell.playerImageView.image = playerArray!.filter({ $0.position == pos })[indexPath.row].image

        resizeCollectionView() //Setup view size after items calculated
        return cell
    }
```

**Resize method (called above):**

```
func resizeCollectionView() {

        self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        if self.playerArray!.filter({ $0.position == pos }).count <= 4 {
            self.nextBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -120).isActive = true
        }
        else {
            self.nextBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true            
        }
        self.nextBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

*Written in swift 4*

Can anyone point me in the right direction why this issue occurs? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
@Dris, when I add your change for the constraint the result is : 
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can change the logic behing the constraints. If you want your save button on the same positions every time, and doesnt matter the size of the collection view, add `self.nextBtn.bottomAnchor.constraintt(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -16)` instead of topAnchor to collectionView.

Comment: @Dris look at my edit. When i add this line of code instead of my current constraints the next button is placed at the top of the screen?

Comment: Are you sure about your constraints? Can you paste the new line?

Comment: Resolved by adding two constraints in storyboard. 

1. Next top = contentView.bottom -100
2. Next.top >= collectionView.bottom  + 100